# Скрытие блока в iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, javascript

Допустим, есть вот такой iframe:

```
<iframe width='500' height='500' src='http://сторонний_сайт.ru/lalala.html'></iframe>
```

Вот приблизительный body lalala.html:

```
<div id='block' style='padding: 30px; background-color: #ff0000'>некий текст</div>
```

И всё. Нужно как-то скрыть этот блок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, решил. Это я делаю расширение для chrome, и нужно просто сделать так:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "matches": ["http://сторонний_сайт.ru/forum/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"]
    }]
```